# escaping apostrophe in javascript shows extra backslash

Tags: javascript, codeigniter, escaping

I'm using language files with Codeigniter to display any kind of messages, such as:

```
$lang['home']['msg1']  = "We couldn\'t proceed...";
```

I'm calling these variables in Javascript (in my footer) with the following code:

```
var Settings = {
    base_url: '<?php echo base_url(); ?>',
    hire_text: '<?php echo $this->lang->line('hire'); ?>',
    msg1: '<?php echo $this->lang->line('home')['msg1']; ?>'
}
```

Unfortunately I haven't managed to handle properly sentences with an apostrophe. I've tried the following:

```
$lang['home']['msg1']  = "We couldn\'t proceed...";
```

shows:

```
We couldn\'t proceed...
```

and

```
$lang['home']['msg1']  = "We couldn't proceed...";
```

returns a Javascript error message

After reading multiples questions/posts I still can't figure out the proper way

Comment: just for grins what happens when you do ...='We couldn\'t proceed...';

Comment: Javascrip error as well, as my source code will become `var Settings = {
    msg1: 'We couldn't proceed...',`
}

Comment: Just for fun, Try `$lang['home']['msg1']  = 'We couldn\\\'t proceed...';`

Comment: Still one backslash displayed in the page with your suggestion. If I used your suggestion with double quotes I get the JS SyntaxError

Comment: Use double quotes for values in JavaScript. You are breaking everything there with mixing single quote between JS string and PHP array key. I.e. `hire_text: "<?php echo $this->lang->line('hire'); ?>"` etc.

Comment: @Tpojka thanks it worked using double quotes in JS directly. Post as an answer so I can accept

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are breaking both expressions (JS and PHP) by using single quotes with no escaping. You can escape inside quote mark or use combination of single and double quotes.

```
var Settings = {
    base_url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>",
    hire_text: "<?php echo $this->lang->line('hire'); ?>",
    msg1: '<?php echo $this->lang->line(\'home\')[\'msg1\']; ?>'// should be working either way
}
```